# Codeception raise fatal error with Laravel 4 and Guzzle HTTP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, codeception, guzzle

I'm using Laravel 4.2.* and Codeception 2.* for the record.

When I try to create an acceptance test with Laravel4 module I use this configuration

```
## Other code
config:
      Laravel4:
           # This file is in app/tests/acceptance.suite.yml
            start: '/../../bootstrap/start.php'
            cleanup: true
## Other code
```

And it works, I mean I can build it. But when I run `codecept run` it fails and raise a fatal error.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\Stream\create() (previously
>   declared in
>   phar:///usr/local/Cellar/codeception/2.0.0/libexec/codecept-2.0.0.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/streams/src/functions.php:14)
>   in /Users/Ludo237/Sites/l4/vendor/guzzlehttp/streams/src/functions.php
>   on line 14

The problem seems to be Guzzle. I'm using guzzle on my application but codeception uses it too.

**How can I solve this conflict?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick fix just move the global codeception install inside the project and require it trough composer...